# Bazel - Errors After Renaming WORKSPACE to WORKSPACE.bazel

Tags: bazel

I'd like to be consistent and rename all my Bazel files to `.bazel`, which shouldn't be a problem because it is even mentioned in the [official documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#workspace):

> Bazel also supports WORKSPACE.bazel file as an alias of WORKSPACE file.

So currently I have a [WORKSPACE](https://github.com/flolu/bazel-workspace-rename-issue/blob/196c62046b6aee82d0873d8fc0b7d60cd733067f/WORKSPACE) file and *everything* works totally fine. But after renaming it to `WORKSPACE.bazel` I get those errors when I run my tests via `bazel build //...`

```
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'com_github_pkg_errors' which is a go_repository (rule definition at /home/flolu/.cach
e/bazel/_bazel_flolu/9d1b897d04e9a8aa4b1c82ee6b746d0c/external/bazel_gazelle/internal/go_repository.bzl:189:17):
 - <builtin>
 - /home/flolu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_flolu/9d1b897d04e9a8aa4b1c82ee6b746d0c/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/repositories/go_repositories.bzl:44:9
 - /home/flolu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_flolu/9d1b897d04e9a8aa4b1c82ee6b746d0c/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/nodejs/image.bzl:44:5
 - /home/flolu/Desktop/workspace-rename-issue/WORKSPACE.bazel:45:1
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'com_github_pkg_errors':
   Not a regular file: /home/flolu/Desktop/workspace-rename-issue/WORKSPACE
ERROR: /home/flolu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_flolu/9d1b897d04e9a8aa4b1c82ee6b746d0c/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/container/go/cmd/join_layer
s/BUILD:3:1: @io_bazel_rules_docker//container/go/cmd/join_layers:go_default_library depends on @com_github_pkg_errors//:go_default_library in repository @com_github_pkg_errors which failed to fetch. no such package '@com_github_pkg_errors//': Not a regular file: /home/flolu/Desktop/workspace-rename-issue/WORKSPACE
ERROR: Analysis of target '//service:image' failed; build aborted: no such package '@com_github_pkg_errors//': Not a regular file: /home
/flolu/Desktop/workspace-rename-issue/WORKSPACE
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.815s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (25 packages loaded, 665 targets configured)
    Fetching @com_github_google_go_containerregistry; fetching
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

## Try it yourself

All the steps to reproduce a minimal example are included in this small repository: https://github.com/flolu/bazel-workspace-rename-issue

Comment: Maybe this one of the rare cases where a `bazel clean --expunge` makes sense

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work

Comment: Did you delete `/home/user/.cache/bazel/` (Windows: `C:\Users\user\_bazel_user`)? I switch for some projects to `WORKSPACE.bazel` and it worked.

Comment: Did take some time because of my slow internet, but the error still persists :(

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that fetches only 'com_github_pkg_errors and gives the error  `ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'com_github_pkg_errors'` - did you rename all occurrences of WORKSPACE to WORKSPACE.bazel?

Comment: @Vertexwahn I've now added a minimal example to my question, you can try it yourself

Comment: Mabye the rules you are using contain something like this: `project_dir = ctx.path(ctx.attr.file_in_project).dirname` and for some reason `.bazel` is stripped - I think the reason are the rules who try to find the location of the workspace file somewhere

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, but I don't have used something. But it is probably an issue in `@io_bazel_rules_docker` :/